# Categorizing items with names on Excel

Tags: excel, categorization

I am trying to rearrange matrix elements to categorize items matching with names. For example:

The original matrix:

```
Name, item1, item2, item3 ... 

A,    apple, banana, cherry

B,    milk, apple, cherry

C,    milk, chocolate, apple
```

and then I want to convert this matrix into:

```
items, names

apple, A B C 

banana, A

cherry, A B

milk, B C

chocolate, C
```

Currently, I am just copying and pasting on excel, and it is very inefficient. Is there any way to categorize the items?

Comment: it shows Excel 365 (16.0.11929.20384).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please refer to this [article](https://www.excelcampus.com/install-power-query/) to find out how to use **Power Query** on your version of Excel. It is available in **Excel 2010 Professional Plus and later versions**. My demonstration is using **Excel 2016**.

Steps are:

1. Add your source data to power query editor;
2. Highlight all `Item` columns, use **Unpivot Columns** function under `Transform` tab to unpivot these columns, then sort your table by `Value` then by `Name` column;
3. Use **Group By** function under the `Transform` tab to group the `Name` column by `Value` column as set out below:

[image: Group By]

4. Go back to the last step in the **APPLIED STEPS** section on the right hand side, go to the formula bar to replace this part of the formula `List.Sum([Name])` with `Text.Combine([Name]," ")`;
5. **Close & Load** the result to a new worksheet (by default).

If all your names are consistent without any hidden spaces in front or at the end of the string, you should have the following as a result:

[image: Result]

Here is my Power Query **M code** for your reference:

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table3"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Name", type text}, {" item1", type text}, {" item2", type text}, {" item3", type text}}),
    #"Unpivoted Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(#"Changed Type", {"Name"}, "Attribute", "Value"),
    #"Sorted Rows" = Table.Sort(#"Unpivoted Columns",{{"Value", Order.Ascending}, {"Name", Order.Ascending}}),
    #"Trimmed Text" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Sorted Rows",{{"Value", Text.Trim, type text}}),
    #"Cleaned Text" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Trimmed Text",{{"Value", Text.Clean, type text}}),
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Cleaned Text", {"Value"}, {{"names", each Text.Combine([Name]," "), type text}})
in
    #"Grouped Rows"
```

Let me know if you have any questions. Cheers :)

Comment: Thanks for the help, Powerquery looks good. But I believe this editor is a bit slow? Perhaps vba is faster?

Comment: @Goldhund yes, just follow Step 4 which is to go back to Step 3 to replace the original formula with the correct one (as the correct one is not a built-in function..yet?)

Comment: oh it was just the powerquery that seemed to be rough, not the process it takes. I think it works fine.

Comment: by the way, is there any command that counts the number of names? 3 for apple, for example.

Comment: @Goldhund Replace Step 3 to Group By `Value` Column and set the Operation to `Count Rows` instead. If you think my answer is working for you just fine, please consider marking it as the solution by clicking the tick mark under the down vote button next to my answer :) I suggest you to play with the PQ editor to test out each function when you have time. If you come across any specific problem, you can ask a new question, show what you have tried, and specify what you want to achieve, and with `#powerquery` in the tags, so other contributors (if not me) can help you out.